# How to send Crystal Reports server and path parameters?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm working in Visual Studio C# and want to make reports with Crystal Reports, but this software will be installed in another computer, so my question is how I can send as a parameter the local server name and the path where the file .rpt will be located to the Crystal Report so the application would be generate the report in any computer where it being executed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make the crystal Report as shared resource, use [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) store your UNC Path in the Cofig file and load the reports normally